# No internet connection on Dell Mini 9 after upgrade

Tags: 10.10, internet, dell-mini-9

I upgraded initially from Karmic to Lucid and then right to Maverick (all in the same day) and since then I've not been able to get online at all. It sees the ethernet but it won't connect, and it doesn't even bother with the wifi.

I have rebooted, reinstalled, left it alone for months and now I'm back at trying to fix it. All the fixes I have read about require internet... which is not an option on this machine.

Comment: People could help you better if you include the make/model of your ethernet card.

Comment: Put you dmesg and /var/log/syslog output into this question please mate.

Answer (score 1):

According to the  [Ubuntu Certification Page](http://www.ubuntu.com/certification/hardware/200908-3475) Ubuntu is compatible with 10.04 LTS (with notes) those notes say:

> **Proprietary drivers required**
>   Installation of a proprietary driver is required for wireless network (WiFi) functionality.

You will need to download and install these drivers for the wireless network connections to work. I know that's not possible on this machine to "download" anything - however there are plenty of questions which outline [How to install packages offline](https://askubuntu.com/search?q=How+to+install+packages+offline). The package you will need for this to work is [bcmwl-kernel-source](http://packages.ubuntu.com/maverick/bcmwl-kernel-source).